# Possible Synthesis of a Polymer

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, synthesis, theoretical-chemistry, polymers

Following a question I have asked previously, what I intend to inquire this time is quite similar as well, except, with a polymer.

So previously I asked whether such monomer PCDO is possible to synthesize.

[image: Phenyl Carbolithia Divinylene Oxide molecule]

That originated from this similar, but different polymer poly-PCDO. It is true that I also don't think this PCDO from my previous question is poly-PCDO after monomerization (I'm still not so sure though). But the PCDO molecule pop out when I was attempting to make this original poly-PCDO a monomer.

[image: Poly-Phenyl-Carbolithia-Divinylene-Ether]

I think the synthesis of the polymer in this structure would be easier to theorize and explain.

One can dehydrate divinyl ether with benzene (or perhaps phenol) and lithonate by condensation polymer.

$$\ce{n(C4H6O + C6H6O + HLiCO3) -> (C11H9LiO4)_{n} + nH2O + nH2}$$

Due to my limited knowledge in this area, I can only assume the phenyl group would most likely bond with lithonate being bonded to the ether already. Would someone explain to me how this will or will not work?

Comment: If you don't mind the question: What properties are you hoping to achieve for your polymer? Are you're trying to obtain a high loading and tight binding with $\ce{Li+}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under acidic conditions, a part of the divinylether will probably just undergo cationic polymerization:

[image: cationic polymerization of divinylether]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you may meant by acidic conditions? Is it the Lithium ion that acts as the cationic initiator?

Comment: @čaritisio Acidic conditions means the the presence of a Bronsted acid that releases a proton. That could even be phenol.